# Presentation of an object in an Eilenberg Moore category by generators and relations

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Let $\cal C$ be a category and let $T \colon \cal C \longrightarrow C$ be a monad. An $T$-algebra $A$ is *presented by generators* $G \in \cal C$ *and relations* $R \in \cal C$ if it is the coequaliser of two morphisms $TR \longrightarrow TG$. See [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generators+and+relations) for more information. Unfortunately, the site does not go into much detail.

I am a bit confused about how this works in practice though. For example, consider the group
$$
A = \langle x,y,z \mid xy=yx \rangle
$$
Let $G = \{x,y,z\}$ and let $R = \{ * \}$ be a singleton. Let $F \colon \mathsf{Set} \longrightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ be the free group monad. Define $s(*) = xy \in FG$ and $t(*) = yx \in FG$. Then $s,t$ extend to group homomorphisms $FR \longrightarrow FG$, and I think that $A$ is the coequaliser of these.

Is that the correct way to think of this?

Comment: That is correct.